# Web scraping different football live scores sites

Tags: python, web-scraping, live

I need livescores of football in a database for an application i want to develope. The apis I found are incomplete or without some functions i need, is legal to web scrape live score sites? I think i could scrape different sites to not create traffic, what do you think? Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about legality of scraping web sites

Comment: Your question is not easy to answer. I suggest to read terms of service from this websites. There is a lot of articles in web about the legality of web-scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it's illegal to parse data off of a website.  You will probably want to do something like this, it's a program that goes to a specified webpage and takes data from a specific line and saves it to a file for another program to use.

```
#this is to get the price of various stocks from Google's search page.     Let's hope this works.
import requests
# Example file for parsing and processing HTML
# import the HTMLParser module
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import time

metacount = 0;

x=0
while x==0:
# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    # function to handle character and text data (tag contents)
    def handle_data(self, data):
        #print data
        pos = self.getpos()
        #print "At line: ", pos[0], " position ", pos[1]
        if pos[0]==154:
            price=data
            print price
            # Open a file for writing and create it if it doesn't exist
            f = open("price.txt", "w+")
            # write some lines of data to the file
            f.write(price)
            f.close()
            # Open the file back up and read the contents
            #if = open("price.txt", "r")
            #if f.mode == 'r':  # check to make sure that the file was opened
        # use the read() function to read the entire file
            #   print('true')



def main():
    # instantiate the parser and feed it some HTML
    parser = MyHTMLParser()
    #stock=open('stocks.txt')
    stockname=raw_input('stock symbol')#stock.read()
    r=requests.get('http://stocks.tradingcharts.com/stocks/quotes/'+stockname)
    #print (r.status_code)
    stuff = r.text
    parser.feed(stuff)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main();
#put it on a timer since the page is updated once every 5 minutes
time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: But I need to develope a public application that use that database, i think that is not so legal, so i wanted to ask

Comment: wait, do you want to scrape it from the webpage or do you want to break in to the database which serves the database?
One is legal but frowned upon by some, the other is decidedly illegal if you don't have privileges to access the DB.

Comment: i'd like to scrape results from page, and there's nothing in the terms of use

Comment: If it's from the page, there shouldn't be any legality issues. If it's publicly accessible, then anyone and anything can and should be able to access it.

Comment: It's from a page publicly accessible, so i could take and use data for my free application, thank you.